# Array mod doesn't seem to produce array for my object that should fit with my numbs path Curve

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Hello, So I downloaded a pillar object as a decoration for my balcony and decided to use the array mod for these objects to fit the curve of my balcony. Before I arrange everything I wanted to experiment with the array mod (thats why everything looks a bit messy on the pic) but the array that should fit the curve doesn't seem to work at all.. I started by drawing the numbs path, and placed that pillar object on the center, then I switched from fixed to fit curve, but as you can see no copys of my object appear at all.. What did I overlook in this process?

Comment: did you apply scale + rotation for curve and object?

Comment: I yes did both, fixed mode copys appear but as soon as i switch to fit curve they dissapear